# Align Image - Skew Correction - JAVA

Tags: java, math, alignment, skew, error-correction

Hi there I have an image with four markers, the image is not properly aligned as you can see in the image below.

[image]

I drew a line using the centroid of my two left markers in the image and the line is not aligned, the image needs some rotation to be fixed.

How can I perform this rotation, how can I know how many degrees I should rotate the image?

I have the two points (my markers) of the center of each marker.

I searched but didn't found anything, someone talked me about skew correction using hough transform, how can I perform that?

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Maybe getting the line equation (polar system) using this two points and then get the angle, is that possible? then I just need to rotate (180º - the resulting angle), right? [math question]

Thank you very much in advance